# need clarification regarding the management of nodes, roles within Chef

Tags: chef-infra, inventory, recipe

I've read quite some documentation regarding chef, from its recipes to roles and the usage of its knife tool. I am comfortable with running recipes and associate them with nodes using roles. The aspects I am not comfortable with is the UI and the internal management of nodes, roles etc. Note that I come from Ansible where every single piece of configuration can be version controlled in a repo such as git for example.

- how do keep track of changes in nodes, etc. in the UI - is there an audit tool to allow us to see what was changed over time? I searched online for a demo but found little info.
- Is it possible to sync-up chef server and a say git repository, so changes in the node, roles etc. definition can be at least seen in there? In ansible I could maintain my expectations in a configuration file and have the tool import it. Is there any way to do sth similar? I read about "infrastructure as code" but isn't it defeating the purpose here that this code cannot easily be version-controlled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me try to clarify...

> - how do keep track of changes in nodes, etc. in the UI - is there an audit tool to allow us to see what was changed over time? I searched online for a demo but found little info.

there are many ways to converge a node (running your recipes), once the convergence is done, the node attributes are stored. where they are stored is dependent on how you converged the node:

- **server\client architecture:** node attributes will be stored on chef server
- **zero\local-mode architecture:** node attributes will be stored in a json file locally

if you configured you [knife correctly](https://docs.chef.io/knife_setup.html) (see [client.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb.html)), you'd be able to use knife to retrieve the node attribute. [for instance](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html):

```
$ knife search "name:node.example.com" --long
```

> - Is it possible to sync-up chef server and a say git repository, so changes in the node, roles etc. definition can be at least seen in there? In ansible I could maintain my expectations in a configuration file and have the tool import it. Is there any way to do sth similar? I read about "infrastructure as code" but isn't it defeating the purpose here that this code cannot easily be version-controlled?

sure it is possible. just place all your cookbooks under source control management.
if you use server\client architecture, then once you complete your cookbook development and testing, [upload your cookbooks to chef-server](https://docs.chef.io/knife_upload.html) and then run chef-client on the node of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not familiar with Chef's UI, I will try to briefly respond to your second question.

You have two options:

1. If you would like to stick to roles you can follow [Policyfile](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_policyfile.html) model/pattern.
2. You can ditch roles. You can switch to wrapper cookbook pattern, where you treat cookbooks like roles. For example, instead of web_server role, you create meta (wrapper) cookbook web_server where you just include other cookbooks or set attributes. You can version wrapper cookbook like any other cookbook. To the nodes, you assign only wrapper cookbooks or you have only one wrapper cookbook per node type.